# SQL Row concatenation with XML PATH and STUFF giving aggregate sql error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml, concat

I am trying to query two tables and get results like the following:

```
Section    Names
shoes      AccountName1, AccountName2, AccountName3
books      AccountName1
```

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA(ID INT, Section varchar(64), AccountId varchar(64));

INSERT dbo.TableA(ID, Section, AccountId) VALUES
(1 ,'shoes','A1'),
(2 ,'shoes','A2'),
(3 ,'shoes','A3'),
(4 ,'books','A1');

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB(AccountId varchar(20), Name varchar(64));

INSERT dbo.TableB(AccountId, Name) VALUES
('A1','AccountName1'),
('A2','AccountName2'),
('A3','AccountNAme3');
```

I saw a few questions answered saying to use "XML PATH" and "STUFF" to query the data to get the results I am looking for, but I think there is something missing.  I have tried the below query and get the error message:

> Column 'a.AccountId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't have it in the SELECT clause of either query, but I assume the error is because AccountId is not unique in TableA.

Here is the query I am currently trying to get working correctly.

```
SELECT section, names= STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + Name FROM TableB as b 
WHERE AccountId = b.AccountId
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableA AS a
GROUP BY a.section
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, I missed a step in the relationship. Try this version (though [Martin's will work as well](http://pastebin.com/Fz601fDC)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.section, names= STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + b.Name 
    FROM dbo.TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
    ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
    WHERE a.Section = o.Section
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM dbo.TableA AS o;
```

An approach that is *at least as good*, but sometimes better, is switching from `DISTINCT` to `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT o.section, names= STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + b.Name 
    FROM dbo.TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
    ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
    WHERE a.Section = o.Section
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM dbo.TableA AS o
GROUP BY o.section;
```

At a high level, the reason `DISTINCT` applies to the entire column list. Therefore for any duplicates it has to perform the aggregate work for every duplicate before applying `DISTINCT`. If you use `GROUP BY` then it can potentially remove duplicates *before* doing any of the aggregation work. This behavior can vary by plan depending on a variety of factors including indexes, plan strategy, etc. And a direct switch to `GROUP BY` may not be possible in all cases.

In any case, I ran both of these variations in [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer). The plans are different in a few minor, uninteresting ways, but the I/O involved with the underlying worktable is telling. Here is `DISTINCT`:

> [image]

And here is `GROUP BY`:

> [image]

When I made the tables larger (14,000+ rows mapping to 24 potential values), this difference is more pronounced. `DISTINCT`:

> [image]

`GROUP BY`:

> [image]

In SQL Server 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT a.section, STRING_AGG(b.Name, ', ')
    FROM dbo.TableA AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
    ON a.AccountId = b.AccountId
    WHERE a.Section = a.Section
    GROUP BY a.section;
```

The I/O here is almost nothing:

> [image]

---

But, if you're not on SQL Server 2017 (or Azure SQL Database), and can't use `STRING_AGG`, [**I have to give credit where credit is due**... Paul White's answer below](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137095/1186) has very little I/O and kicks the pants off of both of the `FOR XML PATH` solutions above.

> [image]

---

Other enhancements from these posts:

- [Grouped Concatenation in SQL Server](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation)
- [Grouped Concatenation : Ordering and Removing Duplicates](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation-2)
- [Comparing string splitting / concatenation methods](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/01/t-sql-queries/comparing-splitting-concat)

Also see:

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Answer (score 12):

I thought I would try a solution using XML.

**[SEDE Demo](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/481209)**

#### Tables

```
DECLARE @TableA AS table
(
    ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
    Section varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    AccountID char(2) NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @TableB AS table
(
    AccountID char(2) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

#### Data

```
INSERT @TableA
    (ID, Section, AccountID)
VALUES
    (1, 'shoes', 'A1'),
    (2, 'shoes', 'A2'),
    (3, 'shoes', 'A3'),
    (4, 'books', 'A1');

INSERT @TableB
    (AccountID, Name)
VALUES
    ('A1', 'AccountName1'),
    ('A2', 'AccountName2'),
    ('A3', 'AccountName3');
```

#### Join and convert to XML

```
DECLARE @x xml =
(
    SELECT
        TA.Section,
        CA.Name
    FROM @TableA AS TA
    JOIN @TableB AS TB
        ON TB.AccountID = TA.AccountID
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES(',' + TB.Name)
    ) AS CA (Name)
    ORDER BY TA.Section
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('Root')
);
```

[image: XML creation query]

The XML in the variable looks like this:

```xml
<Root>
  <TA>
    <Section>shoes</Section>
    <CA>
      <Name>,AccountName1</Name>
    </CA>
    <CA>
      <Name>,AccountName2</Name>
    </CA>
    <CA>
      <Name>,AccountName3</Name>
    </CA>
  </TA>
  <TA>
    <Section>books</Section>
    <CA>
      <Name>,AccountName1</Name>
    </CA>
  </TA>
</Root>
```

#### Query

The final query shreds the XML into sections, and concatenates the names in each:

```
SELECT
    Section = 
        N.n.value('(./Section/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    Names = 
        STUFF
        (
            -- Consecutive text nodes collapse
            N.n.query('./CA/Name/text()')
            .value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(8000)'), 
            1, 1, ''
        )
-- Shred per section
FROM @x.nodes('Root/TA') AS N (n);
```

#### Result

[image: Output]

#### Execution plan

[image: Execution plan]