# Trun a query result to argument of EXEC sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I blatantly stole from the answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35529/how-to-select-the-first-10-records-for-each-table-in-the-same-database-using-sql) to make this : (this is not the only case I am looking a solution for)

```
SELECT   'SELECT Top 10 [table] = ''' 
         + REPLACE(name, '''','') 
         + ''', * FROM ' 
         + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]))  
         + '.' 
         + QUOTENAME(name) 
         + ';' as SQLText
FROM     sys.tables AS t
ORDER BY name;
```

The reason was that in the answer the `DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)` was not enough to hold all the tables names, I think we have 120 tables, (or whatever), and the SQL text was being clipped at `NVARCHAR(MAX)` limit.

Maybe in this case can `EXEC sp_executesql SQLText` and unionizing them,
but is there a way to turn all the rows into one text and execute that instead?

Is there a limit on the size of how big text of a stored procedure can be?

Please note, I am not after the answer for this specific case, but this is an example of type of problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't problem with `NVARCHAR(MAX)` limit for sure. 120 tables isn't a lot and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` limit is a way above what is needed here (up to 2 GB data), more information [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639972/4194554).

I've just checked this solution and it works for me (399 tables).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT Top 1 [table] = ''' 
            + REPLACE(name, '''','') 
            + ''', 1 FROM ' 
            + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]))  
            + '.' 
            + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
FROM     sys.tables AS t
ORDER BY name;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

If you want to see the whole content of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` value in SSMS (`SELECT` and `PRINT` have limits), you could do something like that:

```
SELECT @sql AS [processing-instruction(x)]
FOR XML PATH('')
```

As suggested by @Dan Guzman, more reliable approach would be:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = STUFF((SELECT 'SELECT Top 1 [table] = ''' 
                            + REPLACE(name, '''','') 
                            + ''', 1 FROM ' 
                            + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]))  
                            + '.' 
                            + QUOTENAME(name) + ';' 
                     FROM sys.tables AS t
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 1, 0, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Note that the behavior of aggregate string concatenation is undefined with this method, although if often works. It would be better to use an [`XML PATH` technique](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137045/sql-row-concatenation-with-xml-path-and-stuff-giving-aggregate-sql-error). In SQL 2017 and Azure SQL Database, `STRING_AGG` will do this more easily with defined behavior.