# Format a value from other values in the table

Tags: database-design

I have identified a location for data integrity problems in a design for a database I'm planning on building. I have lots of two way connections between maps in a game. These connections cause from 2 to 8 duplicate strings per connection. Due to this I have decided to add a `names` table.

As an example we have two locations Beach and Town, to move between them you need to move into the "Beach to Town" or "Town to Beach" entity.
As I'm defining regions with a tree / graph like structure, there would be five regions in total. The four described earlier. And "Beach - Town Path" which is the parent to both "Beach to Town" and "Town to Beach".

In a table this would look like:

```sql
ID  NAME
1   Beach
2   Town
3   Beach to Town
4   Town to Beach
5   Beach - Town Path
```

I can solve this outside of SQL easily with Python. However I would prefer this logic to be inside the database.

```python
import string

formatter = string.Formatter()

names = {
    1: "Beach",
    2: "Town",
    3: "{names[1]} to {names[2]}",
    4: "{names[2]} to {names[1]}",
    5: "{names[1]} - {names[2]} Path",
}


def get_name(id: int) -> str:
    name = names[id]
    while True:
        segments = list(formatter.parse(name))
        if len(segments) == 1 and segments[0][1] is None:
            break
        name = name.format(names=names)
    return name


print(get_name(1))  # Beach
print(get_name(2))  # Town
print(get_name(3))  # Beach to Town
print(get_name(4))  # Town to Beach
print(get_name(5))  # Beach - Town Path
```

How this works:

1. I have the table imported into Python. (I have used a literal for brevity)
2. We get the name from the table.

   ```python
   name = names[3]
   # name = "{names[1]} to {names[2]}"
   ```
3. We check if the name has segments to be formatted.

   ```python
   segments = list(formatter.parse(name))
   # segments = [('', 'names[1]', '', None), (' to ', 'names[2]', '', None)]
   if len(segments) == 1 and segments[0][1] is None:
   # if False:
   ```
4. We format the name with the linked names.

   ```python
   name = name.format(names=names)
   # name = Beach to Town
   ```
5. We check if the name has segments to be formatted. Since it has we break out of the loop.

   ```python
   segments = list(formatter.parse(name))
   # segments = [('Beach to Town', None, None, None)]
   if len(segments) == 1 and segments[0][1] is None:
   # if True:
       break
   ```
6. Return the desired name.

   ```python
   return name
   # return "Beach to Town"
   ```

Back to SQL. This is an example table containing more examples:

```sql
ID NAME
1  foo
2  bar
3  {names[1]} - {names[2]}
4  {names[1]} - 
5  {names[4]}{names[2]}
```

Whilst I can just use the exact code above and get the desired output.
Is it possible to use SQL with something like the following to get the desired output?

```sql
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = 1 -- "foo"
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = 2 -- "bar"
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = 3 -- "foo - bar"
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = 4 -- "foo - "
SELECT name FROM names WHERE id = 5 -- "foo - bar"
```

There are no limit on how the data is stored or retrieved, except that duplicate names are not allowed and the parsing must happen in SQL.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right, but [could it be what you're looking for](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137045/sql-row-concatenation-with-xml-path-and-stuff-giving-aggregate-sql-error)? What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Ronaldo If I don't get any answers that'll be a good starting point to find a solution myself. Thank you. I could probably get it to work if I change the table to `["foo", "bar", "-"]` and have a second one with `[[1, 3, 2], [1, 3]]`. However the last format is not going to work. I have not selected an RDBMS yet.

Comment: Databases barely function as a templating engine. I suggest editing the question and describing more your map connections and what you need to retrieve and I'm sure some answers will come up with the way to do that with databases.

Comment: @danblack Strange that you think I'm hiding things. No, this is really all I need.

Comment: I think you've invested in a solution that isn't implementable, or at least, not implementable with any performance, elegance, maintainability. There's some similarities in structure to something that recursive CTEs may be able to solve. I don't however follow the mappings of connections and what you need. I've asked for more information to try to give you a better solution. Strange that you think this is all you need and it will be possible. If so, good luck, I wish you well.

Comment: To me it is unclear what you want. Do you want to replace the names in the column with a normalized form upon `SELECT`? If yes, describe what result you expect for what data in the table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes. I did "Is it possible to use something like the following to get "foo-bar"?" "Is it also possible to get the output "foo-bar" if I use `WHERE id = 5`?" I have added more description with more example IO

Comment: As already said by others your problem statement is not clear. You mention “maps”. Are “foo” and “bar” map names ? You mention “two-way” connections between maps. Meaning row #3 represents a connection from foo to bar ? Also the other way around ? What about row #4 ? That is not a connection, right ?

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind Why is everyone so hooked on these mostly unrelated relations, when the problem is duplicate names XD God SE is useless man.

Comment: What you seem to ask is how to represent many to many relationship in a relational model ? That is pretty simple and well understood: a table of MAPS (id, name) and one of CONNECTIONS (id1, id2). Finding what map is connected to what other map(s) is then a simple 3-way join.  If you need more complex operations (for example: finding patterns like maps connected to maps connected to maps, or loops in map connections) then you need recursive queries or even a graph-oriented model with graph traversal and graph algorithms...

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind No the problem is ***data integrity problems*** from ***duplicate names***. I know how to connect these entities which is not the question here, it is just about all these hundreds and thousands of ***duplicate names***.

Comment: Duplicate names. Like: only one map can have the name “foo” ? A simple unique constraint does that.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind No like; foo, bar, Beach, Town, "{} to {}" and "{} - {} Path". If Beach is renamed to "Great Beach" I haz problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107214/discussion-between-albert-godfrind-and-soham-mcdonalid).

Answer (score 2):

While clarifying your problem you say "how can I make it so if I ever rename Beach I don't have hundreds of potential problems?" This sounds like a normalization problem to me. Looking at the examples above I think you're mixing data and formatting inside the database, then trying to untangle that in processing.

Starting from an analysis of the problem domain it looks like you have two entity types - Location (or `names`) and Path, where a Path connects exactly two Locations. This I would implement as two tables. As you're concerned about changing natural keys without touching many rows I'd implement surrogate primary keys (using pseudo code since each DBMS's dialect will vary).

```
Location
  LocationId    int primary key
  LocationName  char(999) not null

Path
  FromLocationId int not null FK references Location.LocationId
  ToLocationId   int not null FK references Location.LocationId

  Primary key (FromLocationId, ToLocationId)

insert Location values (1, 'Beach');
insert Location values (2, 'Town');
insert Path values (1, 2);
```

The presentation can be taken care of in SQL if you really want to, though I'd suggest letting the persistence classes of the application take care of it:

```
select 1 as ID, l.LocationName
from Path p
inner join Location l
  on l.LocationId = p.FromLocationId

union all

select 2, l.LocationName
from Path p
inner join Location l
  on l.LocationId = p.ToLocationId

union all

select 3, f.LocationName + ' to ' + t.LocationName
from Path p
inner join Location f
  on f.LocationId = p.FromLocationId
inner join Location t
  on t.LocationId = p.FromLocationId

union all

select 4, t.LocationName + ' to ' + f.LocationName
from Path p
inner join Location f
  on f.LocationId = p.FromLocationId
inner join Location t
  on t.LocationId = p.FromLocationId

union all

select 5, f.LocationName + ' to ' + t.LocationName + ' Path'
from Path p
inner join Location f
  on f.LocationId = p.FromLocationId
inner join Location t
  on t.LocationId = p.FromLocationId;
```

Because of the UNION ALL each path will produce five rows of output. These are distinguished by the constant-valued ID column in each sub-query so a `where ID = ..` query will work as you imagine.

Likely you will have more than one path in your database. It may be worth adding the column PathId to Path. Then your application queries become `where PathID = xxx and ID = 5`.

Now if you rename "Beach" to "Banana" exactly one column of one row changes (just like 3NF says it should) but all results return the new name, guaranteed, with no possibility of inconsistent results.

Comment: Yes this is just a normalization problem. I will try to see if I can implement this as I need. However this is forcing nodes to become edges. "Beach to Path" has a shape size and position on the map, just like "Beach" has a shape size and position on the map. This is just about generating names, as the edges just makes things confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach to fixing this is to split the `Names` table into two tables and a view.

1. `Segments` - First we can split the string into segments.
   From here we can only build a name from joined segments.
2. `NameSegments` - We need to join a `NameId` and multiple `SegmentId`, and so we can build a simple table with both IDs.
3. To be able to access the names in the desired form (like a table) we can build a view.

   This view iterates through the `NameSegments`; grouping all the values with the same `NameId` together.
   When grouping we just join all the referenced `Segments`' `Segment`.

   In short this is basically just:

   ```
   {
       n.NameId: ''.join([Segments[s].Segment for s in name.Segments])
       for n in names
   }
   ```

```sql
CREATE TABLE Segments (
    Id serial primary key,
    Segment varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE NameSegments (
    NameId integer,
    SegmentId integer
);

CREATE VIEW Names AS
SELECT
    ns.NameId,
    string_agg((
        SELECT
            s.Segment
         FROM Segments s
        WHERE s.Id = ns.SegmentId
    ), '') AS Name
 FROM NameSegments ns
GROUP BY ns.NameId;


INSERT INTO Segments (Segment) VALUES
    ('Beach'),
    ('Town'),
    (' to '),
    (' - '),
    (' Path');

INSERT INTO NameSegments (NameId, SegmentId) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 2),
    (4, 3),
    (4, 1),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 2),
    (5, 5);
```

Whilst this works this is not formatting data. It's just concatinating strings.

And so I would add three new tables.

1. `NameFormats` - This acts similarly to `NameSegments` however it just defines which format a name should have.
2. `Formats` - At the core this acts like `NameSegments`.

   - We will add a `FormatTypeId` to determine the type.

     When this is in 'raw mode' the code works exactly like `NameSegments` did.
   - When this is in 'segments mode' this will however lookup the desired NameSegment and then use that's link to determine which Segment to return.

     **Note**: To ensure the correct value is picked I added an `Index` value to the `NameSegments` table.

   This makes it so the format's Value either points to the Segment, or to the NameSegment that points to the Segment.
3. `FormatTypes` - A fairly optional table as the IDs are hard coded. This is good if you want to store more information about the type.

```
CREATE TABLE FormatTypes (
    Id serial primary key,
    Name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO FormatTypes (Name) VALUES
    ('raw'),
    ('segment');

CREATE TABLE Segments (
    Id serial primary key,
    Segment varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Formats (
    Id integer,
    FormatTypeId integer,
    Value integer
);

CREATE TABLE NameSegments (
    NameId integer,
    SegmentId integer,
    Index integer
);

CREATE TABLE NameFormats (
    NameId serial primary key,
    FormatId integer
);

CREATE VIEW Names AS
SELECT
    nf.NameId,
    string_agg((
        SELECT
            string_agg((
                CASE WHEN f.FormatTypeId=1 THEN (
                    SELECT
                        s.Segment
                     FROM Segments s
                    WHERE s.Id = f.Value
                ) ELSE (
                    SELECT
                        s.Segment
                     FROM NameSegments ns
                    INNER JOIN Segments s
                       ON s.Id = ns.SegmentId
                    WHERE ns.NameId = nf.NameId
                      AND ns.Index = f.Value
                ) END
            ), '')
         FROM formats f
        WHERE f.Id = nf.FormatId
    ), '') AS Name
 FROM NameFormats nf
GROUP BY nf.NameId;

INSERT INTO Segments (Segment) VALUES
    ('Beach'),
    ('Town'),
    (' to '),
    (' - '),
    (' Path');

INSERT INTO Formats (Id, FormatTypeId, Value) VALUES
    (1, 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (2, 1, 3),
    (2, 2, 2),
    (3, 2, 1),
    (3, 1, 4),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (3, 1, 5);

INSERT INTO NameSegments (NameId, SegmentId, Index) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 1, 1),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 2, 1),
    (4, 1, 2),
    (5, 1, 1),
    (5, 2, 2);

INSERT INTO NameFormats (FormatId) VALUES
    (1),
    (1),
    (2),
    (2),
    (3);
```

With the above code there is no transformation for getting `{names[4]}{names[2]}` to work.
However, you can probably add another `CASE` statement to look up the `Names`.
Just be careful to not infinitely recurse.